Inequality too complex for Mathematica to solve?
I'm trying to solve some quite complicated inequalities (not a system), one of them for example being
c/y + (2 (xz/y)^((2 \[Alpha])/(1 + \[Alpha])) (\[Alpha] - 1))/(x^2 (1 + \[Alpha])^2)>0
I've tried Reduce, NSolve, FindInstances, but I only get a message that 'System cannot be solved by methods available to [...]'. What could be the issue here?
Additionally, other inequalities I'm checking are significantly longer than the example here. Is it possible that they are too complicated for Mathematica?

What you show above is not an equation and not an  inequalities? also, what are you solving for?  Are you sure xz is not meant to be x z?  Could you show full Mathematica code you used? That will be better even if it did not work?

The exponents will be a problem.  Can you apply a log transform, so that your exponents become factors?  Could you use fixed values of alpha?

Is it possible that they are too complicated for Mathematica?  Yes, it is possible. Even the mighty Mathematica has limits as to what it can solve.

@Nasser I edited the question to include ">0".
The code is Reduce[expression > 0, Reals].

@mikado I will try applying log tranform.
I actually want to get conditions on alpha, such that the expression is positive, so they shouldn't be fixed.

V 14
Reduce[c/y + (2  (x  z/y)^((2  α)/(1 + α))  (α - 
        1))/(x^2  (1 + α)^2) > 0, {c, y, α, x, z}, Reals]

Gives very very long result in about 20 seconds on my PC. Note the changed your xz to x z as I think this is what you meant?
If you have assumptions on the parameters that will also help add them. Example, some ranges and so on.
